# PHP MYSQL Select All, no data in results

Tags: php, mysql

It's probably another simple solution, but I can't seem to find it. Whenever I use a select all statement my query will show that there are results, but it does not display them. It can show me like 50 results and all without the row data. Any help is appreciated. The moment I use SELECT name FROM it does work.

Thanks in advance.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

{
echo "result<br>" . $row[name]."";
}
```

Comment: try doing print_r($row); instead of echo $row[name]

Comment: Also change it to $row['name'] instead of $row[name]

Comment: Like this?
    print_r ("result<br>" . $row['name']."");

Still nothing. Just shows me a whole bunch of "results" but not the row data.

Comment: remove the echo line and add print_r($row);

Comment: php fieldnames are case sensitive. Try 'Name' or whatever your field is written like. And pls always look at the warnings. They would have told you already everything.

Comment: and that ladies, is what happens when you don't check for errors.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Solarflare! It's weird, it works only as "Name" in *, but if I select the column directly it works as "name". Anyway, this works, so tons of thanks.

Also, no warnings were shown. It found results, it didn't show them.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo. `name` isn't anything in php. You probably wanted to insert a string called `'name'` as the key for the associate array like so:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

{
  echo "result: " . $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

Or you could just use `print_r()` like so:

```
print_r($row);
```

that should work for you.

Comment: There's no typo. Name just refers to the field I need. When I type name instead of * it shows the data. When I type *, the data is gone. It shows it has found ## of rows, just doesn't return the data.

print_r($row); does nothing either.

Comment: @Viz but if you type `name` without the quotations in your PHP code, it won't recognize it as a string. the php code requires it to have quotations. Have you at least tried doing it as my answer suggests?

Comment: Without the quotes, PHP would treat `name` as a string, so it should work; though it will generate a warning message.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by @Webeng, your query contains another issue:
`table` is a mysql [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) which needs to be escaped when used in a query. They are escaped by using backticks  (`) as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: I was going to upvote and say that I didn't know you could use tilde to escape reserved words. Still upvoting, but it seems to me that you indeed can't :-)

Comment: You are correct, my bad. I'll edit the answer accordingly. Thanks pointing that out!

Comment: I'm using table only in my example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the table *is* empty, your result is likely due to the fact that whatever "name" is, it isn't in the associative array returned.

Also, check `$result` to ensure there haven't been errors, and/or print the number of found rows in the recordset.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Result: <br />";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "    {$key} = {$value} <br />";
    }
}
```

You *might* have some weird name issues here, that results in **two** columns called "name" (lowercase) being sent to PHP. When you select "name" explicitly you get the first. When you select "*" and get both, the second overwrites the first. This can happen in more complex queries than yours:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name FROM a JOIN b ...
```

will *not* return the associative array one might expect. The same would happen with

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ...
```

since both have a "name" column.

If you **literally** queried the `name` column from a `table` table (i.e., "name" and "table" weren't just placeholders), then that's a SQL syntax error right there - you need to escape the table name with quotes or tick marks. This seems unlikely since you say that replacing the asterisk with 'name' does work.

## Solution

Turns out MySQL is a little tricky in handling names, and this has an effect on the PHP side of the equation:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test1 ( Name integer );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ( 5 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select name from test1;
+------+
| name |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * from test1;
+------+
| Name |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The first SELECT returned a field called "name". The second returned a field called "Name", with a capital N. The two fields aren't the same.

If you have error reporting turned on and display activated, you should see a PHP message to this effect:

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Name in test.php on line 8
```

## Brute force debugging

Next time, in addition to having error reporting set to maximum, you can also print out one row like this:

```
print_r(array_map('htmlentities', $row));
exit();
```

and inspect the row contents in the browser. I've had strange things - never like this, I'll admit - happen to me due to the *What You See Is **NOT** What You Got* effect.

Comment: Table is not empty. When I type name instead of * it returns the row data. But with * it doesn't. Though it does show it has found ## of rows.

I tried your method, and it names all the columns ## of times, but no row data.